# Как правильно говорить: "метр двадцать" или "метр двести"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, правила, разговорная-речь

Доброго всем времени суток!
Намедни с коллегой разгорелся спор: а как же правильно говорить "метр двадцать" или "метр двести", когда имеешь ввиду 1,2 м(1200 мм)?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плотники обычно мерят с точностью до сантиметра: «метр двадцать». В профессиональном общении проектировщики, проектанты, строители переходят на миллиметры: тысяча двести. Употребление «метр двести» не встречается, ибо есть смешение единиц измерения.

Answer (score 1):

В повседневной жизни принято считать, что в метре сто сантиметров. Значит, 1,2 м это один метр двадцать сантиметров или **метр двадцать**.